# how to keep the value of a variable outside method in JS?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have this problem, when I change the value of a variable inside my function if i want to use it outside of it, the vaalue of the variable returns to 0, but inside of it, the value it's changed.

I need to know a way to keep the value of the variable outside the function.

Here is my current code:

```
function getCarsWithNoStatus() {
   var statusName = [];
 // We set the total counters for the areas
   var totals = {bodyshop: 0, paintshop: 0, assembly: 0};
 // var tmpTotal = 0;


        WebApiFactory.getNoStatusOrders(bodyShop1).then(function(statusMonData) {
            for(var statusProperty in statusMonData.NoStatusOrders) {
                statusName = statusProperty;
                for (var j = 0; j < statusMonData.NoStatusOrders[statusName].length; j++) {
                    if (typeof statusMonData.NoStatusOrders[statusProperty][j] !== null) {
                        totals.bodyshop++;
                        console.log(totals.bodyshop); //here shows correct value
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        console.log(totals.bodyshop); //value returns to 0

  }
```

Comment: Why not declare `totals` outside `getCarsWithNoStatus()` ?

Comment: the problem is that your console.log(totals.bodyshop);  that is outside, gets executed before the promise is returned..

Comment: Which console.log prints first? Is WebApiFactory.getNoStatusOrders(bodyShop1) an ajax call?

Comment: @Amit you're right it's an ajax call and the second console.log is the one that gets printed first

Answer (score 0):

The value of `totals` is being modified in an asynchronous code, so your `console.log` is being executed before the asynchronous code is finished. When working with such code you usually want to return a `Promise` or execute a `callback` after the async code is finished executing.

Comment: How do I execute a callback? for this case?